# How to calculate a median on a group in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, median, ssrs-grouping

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 to do some reports in my project, In one of my report i want to display the median of login duration along with average total etc. and the users are grouped by region and country and I want the median of that group.

I have tried following link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2008/07/20/using-group-variables-in-reporting-services-2008-for-custom-aggregation.aspx

but here I'm getting only the median of entire login duration not for the grouped items while using this so all the medians are same. it should be different for different groups by region or country.

Comment: Did you try the method found here, [Calculate a median on a group in SSRS](http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2008/07/calculate-median-on-group-in-ssrs.html)?

Comment: I think I've just asked a similar question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947709/ssrs-median-by-group-jagged-array?noredirect=1#comment48016553_29947709

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the problem is that you can only use the vbCode only on one set of data, since there is a global shared variable "values".
To tackle this issue, I used the following query inside a subreport for each

Median:

```
Select Median.*, (Convert (decimal, Median.bh) + Convert(decimal, Median.th))/2 as MedainResult

from(
    sELECT 
    (SELECT max(finalGrade)
        from
        ( SELECT       top 50 percent finalGrade
        FROM  GradeTable
        WHERE (TermCode = 201410) (CRN = 11735)
        order by finalGrade) as BottomHalf) as bh
,
  (select min(finalGrade)
  from
   ( SELECT  top 50 percent finalGrade
    FROM  GradeTable
    WHERE (TermCode = 201410) (CRN = 11735)
    order by finalGrade desc
    ) as TopHalf
  ) as th
) as Median
```